# Sync scrolling of multiple RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager showing a fragment per page. This fragment holds a list of items inside a RecyclerView. The list of items is always the same size and the views for the items are also of the same height. When scrolling one of the RecyclerViews, I want the other RecyclerViews to scroll at the same time and the same distance. How would I synchronise the scrolling of the RecyclerViews?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple RecyclerViews? Why not just use one `StaggeredRecyclerViewAdapter` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, it allows you to set the number of columns you need. Here is a good example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq3Wvcy1kHo https://github.com/mitchtabian/Recyclerview/tree/master/RecyclerViewStaggered

Answer (score 27):

Here was my solution. The less the code the better...

lvDetail & lvDetail2 are the RecyclerViews you want to keep in sync.

```
    final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener[] scrollListeners = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener[2];
    scrollListeners[0] = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener( )
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            lvDetail2.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[1]);
            lvDetail2.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            lvDetail2.addOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[1]);
        }
    };
    scrollListeners[1] = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener( )
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            lvDetail.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[0]);
            lvDetail.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            lvDetail.addOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[0]);
        }
    };
    lvDetail.addOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[0]);
    lvDetail2.addOnScrollListener(scrollListeners[1]);
```

Comment: There are times where those 2 get out of sync (because we rely on `scrollBy`). What then?

Comment: if you fling one of the RV, they get out of sync.

Comment: Guys how can I achieve this out of sync? I try flinging here and there and no effect, works well...

Answer (score 19):

I believe it is relevant for you to understand its workings, so I am going to explain the whole procedure that I followed to design my solution. Note that this example is for only two RecyclerViews, but doing it with more is as easy as using an array of RecyclerViews.

The first option that comes to mind is listening for scroll changes on both ScrollViews and, when one of them scrolls, use [scrollBy(int x, int y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollBy(int,%20int)) on the other one. Unfortunately, programmatically scrolling will also trigger the listener, so you'll end up in a loop.

To overcome this problem, you will need to setup an OnItemTouchListener that adds the proper ScrollListener when a RecyclerView is touched, and removes it when the scrolling stops. This works almost flawlessly, but if you perform a quick fling in a long RecyclerView, and then scroll it again before it finishes, only the first scroll will be transferred.

To work around this, you will need to ensure that the OnScrollListener is only added when the RecyclerView is idle.

Let's take a look at the source:

```
    public class SelfRemovingOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
    public final void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class from which you need to extend your OnScrollListeners. This ensures that they are removed when needed.

Then I have the two listeners, one for each RecyclerView:

```
private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mLeftOSL = new SelfRemovingOnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        mRightRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
    }
}, mRightOSL = new SelfRemovingOnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        mLeftRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
    }
};
```

And then upon initialization you can setup the OnItemTouchListeners. It would be better to set up a single listener for the whole view instead, but RecyclerView does not support this. OnItemTouchListeners don't pose a problem anyway:

```
    mLeftRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        private int mLastY;

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull final RecyclerView rv, @NonNull final
        MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("debug", "LEFT: onInterceptTouchEvent");

            final Boolean ret = rv.getScrollState() != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
            if (!ret) {
                onTouchEvent(rv, e);
            }
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull final RecyclerView rv, @NonNull final MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("debug", "LEFT: onTouchEvent");

            final int action;
            if ((action = e.getAction()) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && mRightRecyclerView
                    .getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mLastY = rv.getScrollY();
                rv.addOnScrollListener(mLeftOSL);
            }
            else {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && rv.getScrollY() == mLastY) {
                    rv.removeOnScrollListener(mLeftOSL);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(final boolean disallowIntercept) {
            Log.d("debug", "LEFT: onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent");
        }
    });

    mRightRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        private int mLastY;

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull final RecyclerView rv, @NonNull final
        MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("debug", "RIGHT: onInterceptTouchEvent");

            final Boolean ret = rv.getScrollState() != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
            if (!ret) {
                onTouchEvent(rv, e);
            }
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull final RecyclerView rv, @NonNull final MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("debug", "RIGHT: onTouchEvent");

            final int action;
            if ((action = e.getAction()) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && mLeftRecyclerView
                    .getScrollState
                            () == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mLastY = rv.getScrollY();
                rv.addOnScrollListener(mRightOSL);
            }
            else {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && rv.getScrollY() == mLastY) {
                    rv.removeOnScrollListener(mRightOSL);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(final boolean disallowIntercept) {
            Log.d("debug", "RIGHT: onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent");
        }
    });
}
```

Note also that, in my particular case, the RecyclerViews are not the first ones to receive the touch event, so I need to intercept it. If this is not your case, you can (should) merge the code from onInterceptTouchEvent(...) into onTouchEvent(...).

Finally, this will cause a crash if your user attempts to scroll your two RecyclerViews at the same time. The best effort-quality solution possible here is to set `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` in the direct parent containing the RecyclerViews.

You can see an example with this code [here](https://github.com/Stoyicker/RecyclerViewSyncDemo).

Comment: +1, In my case (min: Lollipop, compiling: Marshmallow), omitting `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` did not cause a crash, but instead caused the views to desync.

Comment: If you start dragging while the recyclerview is still settling, then the views desync.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Please see my library for this at https://github.com/Stoyicker/AligningRecyclerView It is used in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jorge.recyclerviewsyncdemo and in the video in the store listing you can see how a drag and then another one before the settling has completed doesn't cause desync.

Comment: But how to do when recycle view items are also recycleviews ? In that case how to organize a synchron scroll ?

Comment: nice sir. but can you give a hint on how to use this for two recyclerviews with different heights and same items? tnks

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found a very easy and short answer.

as Jorge Antonio Díaz-Benito said "The first option that comes to mind is listening for scroll changes on both ScrollViews and, when one of them scrolls, use scrollBy(int x, int y) on the other one. Unfortunately, programmatically scrolling will also trigger the listener, so you'll end up in a loop."

So you need to fix this issue. If you just keep track of who is scrolling they won't loop.

**SOLUTION**

```
public class SelfScrolListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            viewIsScrolling = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is your custom OnScrollListener to check if the scrollState is IDLE. is that is true -> no one is scrolling. so the `int viewIsScolling = -1

now you need to detect if you can scroll.
this is the code:

```
int viewIsScrolling = 1;
boolean firstIsTouched = false;
boolean secondIsTouched = false;
SelfScrolListener firstOSL= new SelfScrolListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (firstIsTouched) {
             if (viewIsScrolling == -1) {
                 viewIsScrolling = 0;
             }
             if (viewIsScrolling == 0) {
                 secondRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
             }
        }
    }
};
SelfScrolListener secondOSL= new SelfScrolListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if(secondIsTouched){
             if (viewIsScrolling == -1) {
                 viewIsScrolling = 1;
             }
             if (viewIsScrolling == 1) {
                 firstRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
             }
        }
    }
};
firstRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        firstIsTouched= true;
        return false;
    }
});
secondRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        secondIsTouched= true;
        return false;
    }
});
firstRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(firstOSL);
secondRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(secondOSL);
```

viewIsScrolling = a global int and set in the beginning to -1; the state that no one is scrolling. you can ad as many recycleviews as you want.

Comment: I tried a similar approach but first RecyclerView does not scroll at all. You can see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330254/sync-scrolling-of-multiple-vertical-recyclerviews) in case you know how to help. Thanks

Comment: Bug, when you fling

Answer (score 3):

kotlin version, this one doesn't handle fling (yet)

```kotlin
class ScrollSynchronizer {
    val boundRecyclerViews: ArrayList<RecyclerView> = ArrayList()
    var verticalOffset = 0

    private val scrollListener = object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            // scroll every other rv to the same position
            boundRecyclerViews.filter { it != recyclerView }.forEach { targetView ->
                targetView.removeOnScrollListener(this)
                targetView.scrollBy(dx, dy)
                targetView.addOnScrollListener(this)
            }
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                verticalOffset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
            }
        }
    }

    fun add(view: RecyclerView) {
        with (view) {
            if (boundRecyclerViews.contains(view)) {
                removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
                boundRecyclerViews.remove(this)
            }
            addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
            boundRecyclerViews.add(this)
        }
    }

    fun scrollToLastOffset(rv: RecyclerView) {
        rv.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
        val currentOffset = rv.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
        if (currentOffset != verticalOffset) {
            rv.scrollBy(0, verticalOffset - currentOffset)
        }
        rv.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
    }

    fun disable() = boundRecyclerViews.forEach { it.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener) }

    fun enable() = boundRecyclerViews.forEach { it.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener) }

    fun addAll(recyclerViews: List<RecyclerView>) = recyclerViews.forEach { add(it) }
}
```

EDIT: following @Groovee60 comment & recommendation, replace the `onScrolled` with this:

```
            // scroll every other rv to the same position
            val otherRvs = boundRecyclerViews.filter { it != recyclerView }
            otherRvs.forEach { targetView -> targetView.removeOnScrollListener(this) }
            otherRvs.forEach { targetView -> targetView.scrollBy(dx, dy) }
            otherRvs.forEach { targetView -> targetView.addOnScrollListener(this) }
```

Comment: Hello, I found that your approach was the easiest to integrate and worked well after adding another touch listener to disable fling gestures. But one refinement was needed - instead of removing the listener for the target view and then re-adding it after the the call to scrollBy(), you should instead remove all listeners in a loop, adjust the scroll of other listeners in a simplified version of your loop, and then re-add all listeners in a loop.

Comment: @Groovee60 yeah this was pretty much experimental at the time, in the actual project I was working on, I ended up using ScrollViews instead of RecyclerViews because the content was static, but ended up doing a ScrollViewSynchronizer class with the same type of functionality, and did something similar to what you said (if I recall).

Answer (score 3):

This solution handles fling. Demo project [here](https://github.com/dima6120/RecyclerViewsSyncDemo)

Suppose you have three horizontal RecyclerViews.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSize"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSize"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv0"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSize"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv1"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1. Add tag to each RecyclerView. For example:

```kotlin
val rvs = arrayListOf(rv0, rv1, rv2)

for (i in 0 until rvs.size) {
    rvs[i].tag = i
}
```

2. Add the same OnItemTouchListener to each RecyclerView to know which RecyclerView is active. If there is already an active RecyclerView then call stopScroll on it (it prevents out of sync if active RecyclerView in fling state)

```kotlin
var touchedRVTag = -1

val itemTouchListener = object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean 
    {
        val rvTag = rv.tag as Int


        if (touchedRVTag != -1 && touchedRVTag != rvTag) {
            rvs[touchedRVTag].stopScroll()
        }

        touchedRVTag = rvTag

        return false
    }

    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
}

for (i in 0 until rvs.size) {
    rvs[i].addOnItemTouchListener(itemTouchListener)
}
```

3. Add the same OnScrollListener to each RecyclerView to scroll other RecyclerViews

```kotlin
val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        val currentRVTag = recyclerView.tag as Int

        if (currentRVTag == touchedRVTag) {
            for (rvTag in 0 until rvs.size) {
                if (rvTag != currentRVTag) {
                    rvs[rvTag].scrollBy(dx, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (i in 0 until rvs.size) {
    rvs[i].addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
}
```

PS: If you want to scroll any RecyclerView programmatically set its tag and then scroll:

```kotlin
touchedRVTag = rv0.tag as Int
rv0.scrollBy(dx, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider just using `NestedScrollView` as parent for `RecyclerViews`. This might need some additional tweaks but general idea is the same:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

If you can't do this for some reasons, you can sync scroll programmatically. Just need to avoid infinite loop of `onScrolled()` event callback as already mentioned in other answers. In other words when you started scrolling programmatically you do nothing inside `onScroll()` until you finished scrolling programmatically. And do not scroll programmatically `RecyclerView` that was originally scrolled.

Put all Recyclers for sync in

```
List<RecyclerView> syncRecyclers
```

Call

```
addSyncListeners()
```

Enjoy

```
public class SyncScrollActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<RecyclerView> syncRecyclers;
    private boolean isProgrammaticallyScrolling = false;


    private void addSyncListeners() {
        for (RecyclerView recyclerView : syncRecyclers) {
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new SyncOnScrollListener());
        }
    }

    private class SyncOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (!isProgrammaticallyScrolling) {
                isProgrammaticallyScrolling = true;
                scrollAll(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                isProgrammaticallyScrolling = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void scrollAll(RecyclerView exceptRecycler, int dx, int dy) {
        for (RecyclerView recyclerView : syncRecyclers) {
            if (!recyclerView.equals(exceptRecycler)) {
                recyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that the NestedScrollView solution should really be considered 1st before writing a full blown scroll sync mechanism, although:

1. NestedScrollView should contain only one child, so just need to nest the recyclerviews inside another layout and it works.

2. NestedScrollView only works for vertical scrolling. for horizontal scrolling we need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable in your pager adapter which will responsible to save current `scrollY` position for its pages and whenever your `getItem(position)` will call update `ListView` positoin have a look at `CacheFragmentStatePagerAdapter` in 
https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/ViewPagerTabActivity.java

Comment: As far as I understand, this doesn't allow me to synchronise the scrolling of the RecyclerViews. It will set the RecyclerView to the current position if the the Fragment holding the RecyclerView is created but it doesn't take into consideration the offset of the RecyclerView. Additionally, if the Fragment isn't recreated it won't be updated to right position.

Comment: Its just a sample code or hint for you, study and implement your logic, i.e. update scrollY every time increasing/decreasing in y axis

Comment: Hmm, I can see that the `ObservableRecyclerView` and the `ObservableScrollViewCallbacks` are useful to figure out the scrolling of one of the `RecyclerView`'s, but this still leaves me clueless on how to set the scrolled distance to the other `RecyclerView`'s.

Comment: Use view pager, add pages of your choice update recycler view on viewpager's onPageSelected

Comment: I have two pages visible on screen at the same time in the `ViewPager`, so this is unfortunately not an option. Additionally this won't take the offset of the currently visible item into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution without any flags and it is quite dynamic

The first thing is you have to create `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and subscribe that listener to each horizontal layout that you wish. `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`:

```
 val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    horizontalScroll(this, recyclerView, dx)
                }
            }



fun horizontalScroll(
            scrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener,
            currentRecycler: RecyclerView,
            dx: Int
        ) {
            for (i in 0..parentRecyclerView.childCount) {
                val childRecyclerView =
                    parentRecyclerView.getChildAt(i)?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
                if (currentRecycler != childRecyclerView) {
                    childRecyclerView?.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
                    childRecyclerView?.scrollBy(dx, 0)
                    childRecyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Please note** that you have to have RecyclerView with the same `layout.id`. Useful in case of vertical RecyclerView with horizontal rows

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
fun start(main: RecyclerView, attach: RecyclerView) {
    attach.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
        main.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
        true
    }
    main.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            attach.scrollBy(dx, dy)
        }
    })
}
```