# Set scroll position to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two RecyclerView's on the screen. Each View takes half of screen surface. Each View have a LinearLayoutManager as Layout manager with LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL flag.

I need the next effect. When I scroll one of this RecyclerView, another View should be scrolled to the same position in the same time. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy)** where params is variables which are initialized by the onTouch event of first recylcerView

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702726/sync-scrolling-of-multiple-recyclerviews) solution for more detail