# How can I merge two ListView / ScrollView / RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I want to implement like this view in my application as shown in an image.

When I scroll any of the lists then another list must be scroll with it, which should look like as single Scroll View.

[image]

## Activity:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private RelativeLayout mContainerLayout;

private Activity mContext;
private RecyclerView mVerticalRV;
private RecyclerView mHorizontalRV;
private ArrayList<Integer> mImageResourceList;
private MenuListAdapter mVerticalListAdapter;
private MenuListAdapter mHorizontalListAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);

    initFragment(view);

    mContext.onWindowFocusChanged(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mVerticalRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mVerticalRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mVerticalRV.setAdapter(mVerticalListAdapter);
    mVerticalListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mHorizontalRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
    mHorizontalRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mHorizontalRV.setAdapter(mHorizontalListAdapter);
    mHorizontalListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mVerticalRV.addOnScrollListener(firstOSL);
    mHorizontalRV.addOnScrollListener(secondOSL);

    return view;

}

private void initFragment( View view ) {

    mContext = getActivity();

    mContainerLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_container);

    mVerticalRV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_vertical);
    mHorizontalRV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_horizontal);

    mImageResourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_1);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_2);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_3);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_4);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_5);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_6);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_7);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_8);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_9);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_10);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_11);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_12);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_13);
    mImageResourceList.add(R.drawable.icon_14);

    mVerticalListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(mImageResourceList);
    mHorizontalListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(mImageResourceList);

}

int vdx;
int vdy;
int hdx;
int hdy;

OnScrollListener firstOSL= new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        vdx = dx;
        vdy = dy;

        mHorizontalRV.smoothScrollToPosition(hdx+dy);

    }

};

OnScrollListener secondOSL= new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        hdx = dx;
        hdy = dy;

    }
};
}
```

## Adapter Class:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Integer> mMenuList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ivMenu;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {

        super(view);

        ivMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_menu);

    }

}

public MenuListAdapter(List<Integer> menuList) {

    this.mMenuList = menuList;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_row_menu, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.ivMenu.setImageResource(mMenuList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMenuList.size();
}
}
```

Also, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702726/sync-scrolling-of-multiple-recyclerviews)

Comment: Share the code what you tried so far .

Comment: Custom RecyclerView LayoutManager

Comment: I tried it with custom RecyclerView, I don't know what I miss in that?