# Android multiple horizontal recycler-view scroll together

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hello i have android app that contain two recycler-view like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerResults"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

how to make this recyclers scroll together  ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Comment: i have two horizontal recyclerview  , i need to make this recyclers scroll horizontally together

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012389/i-want-to-scroll-multiple-recyclerview-at-a-time-how-to-achieve-that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sync scrolling of multiple RecyclerViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702726/sync-scrolling-of-multiple-recyclerviews)

Answer (score 1):

put this code inside **Scroll View**  then it will automatically scroll.
You can also put multiple recycler view inside linear layout and it will work perfectly.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerLay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645502/7522720
this will be helpfull

Comment: This is not what he asked - he is looking for a way to make both of his recyclrView to be scrolled together , you just went and put them inside scrollView(correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: still my answer is same you can also do that my making scrollview which scroll horizontally and both your recycler view will scroll view at the same time. 2,3,4... as many recyclerview you want to add

Comment: how to make scroll view scroll horizontally  ?

Comment: can you show me with image what you want to achieve @MoayedAlayseh

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() { @Override public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) { super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy); if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) { //Calling the method getdata again getData(); } } });
```

Set first recyclerview **x** & **y** to second recyclerview to scroll will first one.