# Two Vertical RecyclerView scrolling at the same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two `RecyclerView`, both have a vertical orientation, I need to scroll one of them so that the second scrolls, that is, their scrolling is synchronous, I thought that it is possible to apply one `LinearLayoutManager` to these two  `RecyclerView` and then it will be work, but in this log, the error `LinearLayoutManager is already attached to a RecyclerView` will be generated, so I don't know how to be, help me find a solution, I need two independent  `RecyclerView` with different adapters, but which scroll synchronously, so do not write about `GridLayoutManager`, thanks.

xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Cod

```
                val RLM_0 = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                rv_0.setHasFixedSize(false)
                rv_0.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                rv_0.layoutManager = RLM_0
                adapter_0 = Adapter_0(itemTasks, requireActivity())
                rv_0.adapter = adapter_0


                val RLM_1 = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                rv_1.setHasFixedSize(false)
                rv_1.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                rv_1.layoutManager = RLM_1
                adapter_1 = Adapter_1(itemTasks, requireActivity())
                rv_1.adapter = adapter_1
```

Comment: The question is why do you need two recyclerviews where the scroll is synchronous? While possible it's a lot more complexity than you probably need. You could just have one recyclerview with a standard linear layout and each item (row) contains the 2 views you `always` want to display side by side. (So not GridLayoutManager :-) )

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Check is: [Sync scrolling of multiple RecyclerViews](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30702726/11439327)

**Solution 2:**

There is an other way to do so, the idea is to disable scroll for each recycler view and surround them with a scroll view.

This is how you can implement it:

```
binding.recyclerViewOne.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
binding.recyclerViewTwo.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
```

And for the layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```